# Custom Shortcode with Dynamic Button

Tags: php, shortcode

I am lost as to how to create a dynamic button shortcode. Depending on the post ID a specific application form is served in a popup by clicking on a button labeled 'Apply'. At the bottom of the page is an [apply button](https://wordpress-562097-1810852.cloudwaysapps.com/current-vacancies/healthcare-assistant/) (which works). I would like to add another 'Apply' button on the right column with a custom shortcode.

```
function apply_button($atts, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array('link' => 'https://recruitly.io/jobs/widget/apply/', 'target' => '' ), $atts));
return '<a class="button" href="'.$link.'" target="'.$target.'">' . do_shortcode($content) . '<span></span></a>';
}
add_shortcode('button', 'apply_button');
```

How would I add the php addition to the URL in 'link' within the shortcode above?

```
<?php echo recruitly_get_custom_post_value('jobId'); ?>
```

I help on what I am missing or done incorrectly would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  Try rewording your question so that an informed and specific answer will help you. Describing the exact problem and asking a specific question will help.  Rule #1 when creating a shortcode: your function should return a result, not echo it directly.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output.

Comment: Another rule when creating a shortcode: You have to name it. (The first parameter can't be empty, which is what you've got in your code.)

Comment: Apologies lads I have tidied that up somewhat above in my original comment and updated the text. I hope it makes a bit more sense now.

Comment: @jdm2112 I hope I have improved the original post

Answer (score -1):

This may not be a direct answer to your shortcode issue.
But try doing it as a post template, from there its easier to handle post data.

You have a working button below the description. Copy it and place it on the bottom. And use Class to trigger your JS this time.